# Лексическая норма

Tags: лексика

Вот предложения:

1. Уверенность каждого за свой завтрашний день.
2. У обеих братьев были одинаковые костюмы
3. Войдя в воду, я почувствовал, что всё тело покрылось мурашками
4. Согласно приказу директора предприятие перешло на круглосуточную работу.
5. Он всегда считал своего соседа отъявленным врагом

Comment: 1 - норм. 2 - у обоих братьев. 3 - норм, но звучит коряво. 4. Обычно пишут согласно приказа (канцелярский язык). 5 - норм.

Comment: -1. Вот это действительно коряво. Свой, имхо, лишнее.  
-2. Не надо ни обеих, ни обоих. Одинаковые  - они всегда у двоих.  
-3. Не вимжу корявости.  
-4. Правильно. "Согласно приказа" - не канцелярит, а просто безграмотность. Правда у неё есть исторические корни.  
-5. Отъявленным может быть негодяй или, например, враль. Враг - заклятым.

Answer (score 1):

В первых двух предложениях - грамматические ошибки. 
 1. Уверенность в завтрашнем дне
 2. У обоих братьев

Речевые недочеты в 1,2 и последнем предложении уже отметили.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос был именно о лексической норме?
Уверенность каждого за свой завтрашний день.-грамматическая ошибка, не лексическая.
У обеих братьев были одинаковые костюмы.-грамматическая (обеих вместо обоих)+ лексическая - плеоназм(смысловое излишество: у обоих одинаковые)
Войдя в воду, я почувствовал, что всё тело покрылось мурашками - норма.
Согласно приказу директора предприятие перешло на круглосуточную работу.-неудачная метонимия:предприятие перешло не на работу, а на график работы.
Он всегда считал своего соседа отъявленным врагом - лексическая несочетаемость.

Comment: В чем было задание, можно только догадываться.
Вряд ли в том, чтобы охарактеризоввать типы ошибок. 
Но, если уж это делать:

В п. 1. Не вижу шрамматической. Вы про "Уверенность за что"? Ой не знаю...   

*Ужасно тревожусь за него и мучаюсь. Но есть какая-то уверенность за него. По-моему, у него моя судьба и он будет иметь благополучный исход. [М. М. Зощенко. «Я не верю, что искусство сейчас возможно». К истории «Перед восходом Солнца» (1934-1944)]*

В п. 4. как раз "график" - излишество. Круглосуточная работа - вполне понятный и естественный оборот.

Comment: Словарь управления говорит "уверенность в чём". У Зощенко-разговорный стиль, речь героя.
перешло на работу - тоже разговорное, упрощённое.перейти употреблено в значении"начать действовать по-другому", а не "переменить работу", здесь другая сочетаемость.

Comment: > У Зощенко-разговорный стиль, речь героя  
      
Господь с Вами. Это автобиография.    
    
> перешло на работу - тоже разговорное  
         
Никак не могу согласиться. "Мы перешли на работу в три смены / вахтовым методом / по бригадному подряду" - какая еще сочетаемость?